# Is every symmetric matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, transformation

I know that

Hermitian matrices are always diagonalizable and real symmetric matrices are real Hermitian matrices and therefore diagonalizable.

But, it is always not the case that a symmetric matrix is a Hermitian matrix.

So my question is I think every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, but is it true for every symmetric matrix?

Also,

$1$ and $-1$ are only possible eigenvalues for real orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Interesting relevant fact: as a consequence of [Takagi's factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi.27s_factorization), every complex symmetric matrix $M$ can be factored in the form $M = AA^T$.

Comment: Related: [$A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})\implies A^TA$ is diagonalisable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611703/a-in-mathrmm-n-times-n-mathbbc-implies-ata-is-diagonalisable)

Answer (score 8):

The matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}i&1\\1&-i\end{bmatrix}$ is (complex) symmetric but has Jordan form $A = VJV^{-1}$ where $J = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $V = \begin{bmatrix}i&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. So, not every (complex) symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

The rotation matrix $R = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$ is real orthogonal and has eigenvalues $\cos\theta \pm i\sin\theta$ which are not $\pm 1$ if $\theta$ isn't a multiple of $\pi$. So, $\pm 1$ are not the only possible eigenvalues for a real orthogonal matrix. However, you can say that the eigenvalues will all  lie on the unit circle and other than $\pm 1$, they will come in complex conjugate pairs.